# How to Terminate or Kill Suspended Task Automatically in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How we can terminate or kill the suspended task automatically in SQL Server 2012? When I run `sp_who2` then it shows many process in a `Suspended` state.

I want to know that is there any way that we can terminate or kill the suspended process/task automatically rather than doing manually.

I know how to kill the `SPID` manually but I want something which can automatically kill those tasks after a defined amount of time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: suspended is a valid state. If you're getting lots of suspended you should work out why it's happening rather than killing them!

Answer (score 6):

Here is simple code snippet that **shows** all suspended SQL tasks and **generates** script to kill them all.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'kill ' + cast(session_id as nvarchar(30)) + ';' 
-- select *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE status = 'suspended'
--and database_id = DB_ID('master')
--and user_id = USER_ID('sa')


print @sql
--EXEC(@sql)
```

To add filter by DB uncomment following line and change DB name

```
and database_id = DB_ID('master')
```

You also can filter it by DB user who is running suspended query

```
and user_id = USER_ID('sa')
```

To execute that generated script automatically **just uncomment last line**

```
EXEC(@sql)
```

Should work on all SQL Server versions. Tested on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and higher

Answer (score 3):

I have written a sample here:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SELECT @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'kill ' , session_id, CHAR(13))
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE status = 'suspended'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you should:

1. Query a special DMV to get PSIDs in SUSPENDED state:

   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE status = 'suspended'
2. Use e.g. cursor on that resultset to kill them one by one
3. Take that script and stuff it into the database job; schedule the job to run regularly

However, if you do that, you should have in mind that suspended query can start running again when resource he's trying to use gets freed/unlocked. And if that query is in e.g. stored procedure which modifies data without transaction, then your kill-automatization could screw up badly by interrupting such process(es).

Comment: how to "Use e.g. cursor on that resultset to kill them one by one"?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ID AS BIGINT
SET @ID = 0
declare @str as nvarchar(Max)
```

this Code Work By Time in this Example :

```
     DECLARE Spliter1_Cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT SPID
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE hostname  ='APPSERVER'
AND datediff(second,last_batch,getdate()) > 999
ORDER BY datediff(second,last_batch,getdate()) DESC

     OPEN Spliter1_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Spliter1_Cursor

        INTO @ID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN  

        SET@str = ''

        SET@str = 'kill '+ cast (@id as nvarchar (max))

        EXEC (@str)

        FETCH NEXT FROM Spliter1_Cursor INTO @ID

        END


    CLOSE Spliter1_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Spliter1_Cursor
```